# Хорошие книги по perl?

Tags: книги, perl

Подскажите книгу по perl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Программирование на Perl](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/147137/)
- [Perl. Изучаем глубже](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4877958/)

Именно в таком порядке.

Comment: Не хотите ссылки оформить по-человечески?

Comment: Я бы в другом порядке начал, ибо 1 книга не совсем та, с которой желательно начинать, после её прочтения вторую можно будет и не трогать.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы не советовал "Программирование на Perl" как первую книгу ))) Предлагаю в качестве первой книги "Learning Perl" от brian d foy - она короче и охватывает все основы. А уж потом да, "Learning more Perl" :) Кстати, от того же автора. А "Programming Perl" можно и потом почитать... :)

P.S. Да, и *обязательно* после этих двух книг прочитать "Perl Best Practices"!!!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от того, знаете ли Вы еще другие языки программирования.
В любом случае могу посоветовать такой список:

1. Программирование на Perl. Часть 1. Общий обзор. Глава 1. Обзор Perl

Данная глава описывает, как появился Perl, что делает его таким. Поэтому данная глава обязательна к прочтению. Следующие главы этой книги лучше всего начинать читать только после ознакомлением с более простыми книгами, а именно:

1. [Язык программирования Perl](http://www.intuit.ru/department/pl/perl/) - рассказывается очень доступно для новичка
2. Шварц Р., Феникс Т., брайан д фой - Изучаем Perl, 5-е издание
3. Шварц Р., Фой Б., Феникс Т. - Perl. Изучаем глубже. 2-е издание
4. Элемент списка

Также, если вы хотите быстро въехать в Perl и до этого программировали на каких-либо языках, то могу предложить книгу

Joseph N. Hall, Joshua A. McAdams, brian d foy - Effective Perl Programming, Second Edition

Например, если хотите сразу понять, что это за переменная $_, то пункте (item) 15 описана эта переменная.

Comment: Учил. и не один.

Answer (score 1):

Я как раз начинал изучать Perl с книги ["O'Reilly: Programming Perl"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596000271.do). Возможно она не очень проста в чтении для человека, начинающего изучать Perl с нуля, да и вообще начинающего программиста, каким я на тот момент являлся, но после её прочтения, причём вдумчивого и с выполнением практических примеров, начинаешь действительно ощущать стиль Perl. Особенно советую осилить главу про регекспы, там много ценной информации. Впрочем эта книга покрывает не все аспекты, хоть и является базовой. Про объектно-ориентированный Perl советую почитать Демина Конвея [Object Orinted Perl](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1884777791) , ну и затем начинать документацию по Moose :)

Answer (score 1):

[Higher-Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/) by Mark Jason Dominus

Очень толковая и интересная книга про использование принципов функционального программирования в Perl.
Но в качестве первой книги по перлу не подойдет.